# dokan sshfs for windows

Tags: sshfs, dokan

I read an article [here](http://cateof.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/dokan-sshfs-readwrite-at-linux-partitions-from-windows/) about dokan sshfs for windows. I want to ask if you know similar software (free or not) in order to access windows partitions from windows. Samba is a always an answer, however I am seeking for something more secure.

Comment: did you not mean "linux partitions from windows"? Please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Dokan SSHFS client with the OpenSSH server for Windows, you can configure OpenSSH like you would on UNIX, then use the Dokan SSH client to connect remotely, just as you would do on UNIX with sshfs.

When you say Samba, so you mean SMB? Samba is the *NIX client/server for SMB.

Answer (score 2):

SSHFS for accessing Windows partitions from Windows ? Did you by any chance mean Linux partitions from windows ?

If windows-windows, then sorry, no. sshfs is a Linux/Unix feature, and microsoft does all it can to NOT make it work on Windows (after all, that would allow to easily and securely migrate from Windows to Linux). On Windows, you use WebDAV to accomplish similar things, needless to say WebDAV is way more insecure than sshfs.

If you meant accessing remote Linux partitions from Windows, then I had the same problem before:

Dokan doesn't work, at least not on Vista x64. (epic bluescreen crash)
The java sshfs explorer on sourceforge doesn't work, either.
Microsoft's services for unix (including sshfs) are only available on Vista 'Ultimate', not on < Ultimate, like my Vista business for example.

There are some commercial solutions, but first, they are way overpriced, and second, I wouldn't trust them, since they don't offer evaluation.

My solution was to install VirtualBox on Windows, and install an Ubuntu guest on it, mounting the host's C drive. You need to set the VirtualBox network adapter to bridged mode to make sshfs work with virtualization. I'm sorry, but so far that's the only free solution that really works...

Answer (score 1):

imdisk driver, see if http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html helps.

From the documentation

> It is even possible to boot a machine
>   with NTFS partitions using a Unix
>   Live-CD and use the included  devio
>   tool to let ImDisk on another computer
>   running Windows on the network mount
>   the NTFS partition on the machine you
>   booted with the Unix Live-CD. This way
>   you can recover information and even
>   run chkdsk on drives on machines where
>   Windows does not boot.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Win SSHFS for awhile, is this what you're looking for?

https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs/

It runs on top of Dokany